# break does not stop repeat when decimals are used R

Tags: r

this works just fine:

```
t <- 2
repeat {
  print(t)
  t = t+2
  if (t == 8){
    break
  }
}
```

this does not:

```
t <- 0.1
repeat {
  print(t)
  t = t+0.1
  if (t == 1){
    break
  }
}
```

why?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am new to R and the link does not help me to solve the problem. is there a straight forward solution to have a loop with decimals where break works?

Comment: try using `isTRUE(all.equal(...))` instead of `==` (as in the accepted answer ;p)

Comment: @ivo The problem lies in floating point arithmetic (as well explained in the linked question). See that `0.1+0.2==0.3` returns `FALSE`. This means that if you keep adding `0.1`, due to floating point precision you don't end up exactly to 1 (and then the exit condition is never met). As for solving your issue: 1) you should never use equality conditions with floating point 2) you may use inequality (for instance `if (t<=1) break`). Keep in mind that the edge case might or might not included in the loop for the same reason (but at least you'll met the condition).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers helped me to understand and figure it out eventually.